# Split Polygon At Vertices While Maintaining Arcs

Tags: qgis

I am looking for a method/procedure of first converting polygon to lines and then splitting at vertices while preserving arcs.

[image]

What I would like to achieve is a line feature class with the lines split where illustrated above.  I have tried to convert to lines but what I get is tiny segments along the arc.  I would instead like a line layer that splits where the vertices are and preserves arcs.

Comment: Could you show the WKT of the source geometry? It is probably some sort of surface because polygons by default consist only from linear segments. GIS programs often linearize arcs but perhaps we can find some way to prevent that.

Comment: It depends on the storage format you use. Shapefiles and many other GIS-file formats can only save lines based on vertices, no real arcs. They have to be approximated by vertices. So you should give as a bit more information about the context/software/file format etc.

Comment: You can ask this same question by using your another tag with arcgis.

Answer (score 4):

In QGIS you can use 'Polygon to lines' and 'Split lines at points' from Processing Tool Box.

Digitizing your image as **test_polygon** and **cut_points2**, I got:

[image]

Applying 'Polygon to lines':

[image]

Applying 'Split lines at points' by using line and points layers.

[image]

Resulting layer (Intersection) preserves arcs.

Comment: Thanks @xunik.  This was my first instinct as well. However, I found QGIS did not produce ideal cogo lines. Unsure why they differed but I was able to produce more desirable results using ArcGIS Pro 'Split into cogo lines' (modify toolbar).